# Nothing is working on my activity. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: android, android-activity

I´m new to Android, but I think I´m trying to do very basic stuff and it's not working.

So here is my activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
public TextView lblHelp;
public ImageButton mBtn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    lblHelp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lbl_main_help);
    mBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn);

    mBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.e("Clicked:", v.toString());
        }
    });

    updateUI();
}

@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    updateUI();
}

@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main2, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_home) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_profile) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_notifications) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_social) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_mobs) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_signout) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

private void updateUI(){
    lblHelp.setVisibility(User.getInstance().getSelected() == null ? TextView.GONE : TextView.VISIBLE);
}
}
```

And here is my `activity_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main2"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main2_drawer" />

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And here my `content_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="0dp"
android:paddingLeft="0dp"
android:paddingRight="0dp"
android:paddingTop="0dp"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="org.app.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main2"
android:background="@mipmap/home_bg">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Your MOB has helped raise"
    android:id="@+id/lbl_main_help"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textColor="#227890"
    android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:background="@mipmap/btn"
    android:layout_below="@+id/raised_container"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**So, I´m having 2 issues with this**

1: the onClick listener for the mBtn never gets called when I tap on it, although I see in logcat something liek this:

```
12-12 01:51:10.110 17475-17475/D/InputEventReceiver: dispatchM{ac=1,id[0]=0,(614,1088),tool=1,flags=0x0,pointCnt=1,evT=423145299,downT=423145224,dev=3,src=0x1002}
12-12 01:51:10.110 17475-17475/V/View: onTouchEvent android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton{42270e50 VFED..C. ...P.... 178,597-901,1320 #7f0e009c app:id/btn}
12-12 01:51:10.110 17475-17475/I/PhoneWindow: cb.dispatchTouchEvent handled
12-12 01:51:10.110 17475-17475/D/InputEventReceiver: finishM{evT=423145299}
```

And on the other hand, the lblHelp never dissapears from the view, even though I see in the console that the visibility changes from 0 to 8.

There must be something very simple that I´m missing here.........

Thanks

**EDIT:**

Ok, I found something. On activity_main.xml, if I comment this out everything works:

```
<!--<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />-->
```

Any idea why that happens and how can I fix it???

Comment: Did you double-check your tag `R.id.btn` in the xml layout?

Comment: Yes, if I put a breakpoint after `mBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn);` I can see all the methods and properties of the button. Even the image that I set as background in the xml

Comment: Post your XMl layout

Comment: @JawadLeWywadi just added them...

Comment: Did your button change UI state when you click on it?

Comment: @MrNeo how can I check that?

Comment: You click on it, and you could see that the border or the color of button change?

Comment: @MrNeo nothing changes. Although I think that´s because its an ImageButton, instead of a Button.

Comment: I think that your buton would be in 2nd layer, have other layer above it

Comment: @MrNeo I actually found out something. Can you check my new EDIT?

Comment: I think you should put `<include layout="@layout/content_main" />` in `app_bar_main2.xml` layout instead of `activity_main.xml`

Comment: That worked @MrNeo!!! Want to put it in an actual answer so I can chose it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your `content_main` layout is set show in `app_bar_main2`:

`tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main2"` so put this line:

`<include layout="@layout/content_main" />`
into  your `app_bar_main2.xml` layout instead of currently in `activity_main.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

Change from  Log.e("Clicked:", v.toString()); to  Log.d("Clicked:", v.toString()); and check

Comment: Hey QuanTV, I actually changed that from my actual implementation just to make the code simpler. If I put a breakpoint, the debugger doesn´t even stop in there...